# Отправка значений и файлов через php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Видел подобные вопросы но там идет отправка Только файла, а не как у меня Файл + строковые данные формы. Собственно сам вопрос есть форма приводить ее полный код не буду так как там все работает. Сам код ajax который берет данные из формы и отправляет их в обработчик:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#addbookbuton", function () {
    var data = new FormData();
    var cud;
    cud = $(this).parent('form').children("select[name='idc']").val();
    data.append('idc', cud);
    cud = $(this).parent('form').children('div').children("select[name='ids']").val();
    data.append('ids', cud);
    cud = $(this).parent('form').children('div').children('div').children("input[type='text']").val();
    data.append('name', cud);
    cud = $(this).parent('form').children('div').children('div').children('label').children("input[name='image']").val();
    data.append('image', cud);
    cud = $(this).parent('form').children('div').children('div').children('label').children("input[name='file']").val();
    data.append('file', cud);
    cud = $(this).parent('form').children('div').children("textarea").val();
    data.append('text', cud);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'hys/ajx/booksload.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(php_script_response){
                //alert(php_script_response);
            }
        });
});
```

проверяя вкладку "сеть" в консоли браузера вижу что все данные которые нужны уходят в обработчик booksload.php однако как раз данные файлов туда не поступают почему то.
к примеру если в файле  booksload.php добавить строку

```
  echo $_POST['name'];
```

то в консоли в вкладке "сеть" при выборе запроса к обработчику в разделе "ответ" будет показано что данные выводятся, но если поместить проверку файла такого вида

```
  if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) &&  sizeof($_FILES['file']['name']) != 0) {
    echo "sdsd";
} else {
     echo "nooo";
}
```

то выдает строку "nooo" - то есть файла по сути не получает, как правильно отправлять такие данные что бы все доходило до обработчика корректно?

Comment: а почему нельзя все данные формы получить serialize() и отправить как json? Ну или хотя бы просто serialize()

Comment: покажи лучше не `echo $_POST['name'];`, а `var_dump($_FILES)`.

Comment: Не очень уверен, но в примере, который я смотрел (не помню уже где, но не суть, он работает хотя бы), там было у файла не .val(), а  .prop("files")[0]

Comment: @АлександрБелинский   NULL выдает\ все таки дело в обработчике - это я как то не так отправляю потмоу что в консоли показывает что отправило: -----------------------------264611403532098
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

C:\fakepath\Проекты.xlsx

Comment: @dantelol, Проверьте на очень маленьких файлах (прям реально малюсеньких - 1-2 байта). в php.ini там должно быть куча настроек выставлено, чтобы можно было нормально принимать большие файлы, я их все точно не помню, сам это делал лишь раз в жизни (посмотрел, сделал, забыл). Там есть: лимит на количество принимаемых за раз файлов, лимит размера файлов, лимит POST запроса, лимит еще какой-то там. И, возможно, я еще что-то забыл. И еще, вроде бы, нужно проверить права на временную папку - возможно Вы не дали бедному apache записывать туда их.

Answer (score 0):

Всё же, замените `children("input[name='file']").val()` на `children("input[name='file']").prop('files')[0]`.

val Вам даст только лишь путь к файлу на Вашем компьютере (что, кстати, для сервера не особо полезная инфа), а вот свойство элемента files - уже куда полезнее, в нём перечислены все файлы (судя по всему их может быть в объекте несколько, я только не знаю зачем, но не суть). Т.к. особо мудрствовать при данной постановке задачи не нужно, поэтому берём просто первый (у программистов он же - нулевой) элемент. Это именно что ни на есть офигенный объект с типом File.

P.S. Как именно устроен сам механизм передачи файла - я не знаю. Можете прочитать и рассказать мне (ну или хотя бы ссылку кинуть).